# Jenkins and git hooks : how to keep only the latest job in the queue?

Tags: jenkins, githooks

I'am using jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url= triggered in the git post-receive hook.

Doing so, I end up with a lot of duplicate jobs in the queue.

Is there a way to keep only the latest one (the one with the latest git hash) ?

Comment: Why not use an update hook instead of a post-receive hook? The update hook has the list of branch pushed, as opposed to the post-receive one, which has the list of all commits pushed. (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks)